# Tricky collinear vectors problem

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

Let *OABC* be any planar quadrilateral. Let $G_1, G_2$ and $G_3$ be the centroids of *OAB, OBC* and *OAC* respectively, and let *G* be the centroid of the triangle $G_1G_2G_3$. Show that the points *O, G* and the centroid *D* of triangle *ABC* are collinear.

I have no idea how to start this any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a coordinate system with its origin at $O$. From:
$$ G_1 = \frac{O+A+B}{3},\qquad G_2=\frac{O+B+C}{3},\qquad G_3=\frac{O+A+C}{3}$$
we get:
$$ \frac{G_1+G_2+G_3}{3} = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{A+B+C}{3} $$
so $O$, the centroid of $G_1 G_2 G_3$ and the centroid of $ABC$ are collinear as wanted.

Comment: You legend, thank you so much!